# Why does undefined variable not return an error in DATA step?

Tags: sas

I wrote the code below to create a "running total" column named "sum". Although it seems to work, I don't understand how SAS is executing this code. When it encounters the statement `sum + var`, how does it know what to do given that `sum` is undefined? Based on the book "The Little SAS Book: A Primer", the SAS data step has a built-in loop that executes the program observation by observation. Given this, how does the program know to do the equivalent of `sum[row2] = sum[row1] + var[row2]` when it gets to the second row?

```
data df;
input var;
datalines;
1
3
.
5
1
;
run;

data df2;
    set df;
    sum+var;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is known as an implicit retain, and is equivalent to:

```
retain sum 0;
sum=sum(sum,var);
```

When you retain a variable, it's value is not set to missing when the PDV is reloaded (it 'retains' the previous value).  It does NOT read from the previous row - a common misconception.

More information on the retain statement is available in the SAS [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm)

Comment: Sum statement also initializes the variable to zero instead of missing.  `retain sum 0;`